# Need to repeat these objects within objects. Can I use $index with ng-repeat to make this happen?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following javascript object called "tabs":

https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8KlX.png

My desired output on page:

```
 section0.title
      children0.title
      children1.title
```

which ends up being

```
 Analytical Balances
      ML
      XS
```

I already have the tab names (tab0.title, tab1.title) repeating as tabbed navigation and am wondering how I might repeat the section names (e.g. section0.title) and the sub-section names (e.g. children0.title).

This what I was thinking would be possible to achieve this outcome:

```
            <div ng-repeat="tab in tabs" track by $index>
              <a>{{ tab[$index].title }}</a>
                    <ul ng-repeat="section in tabs" track by $index>
                      <li>{{ section[$index].title }}</li>
                        <ul ng-repeat="child in children" track by $index>
                          <li>{{ child[$index].title }}</li>
                        </ul>
                    </ul>
            </div>
```

I understand that this would also repeat the tab title, but I figured it would be easier to understand, if I included the top level. Then I can modify it toonly display one tab per page based on an index.

Is using $index like this to reference javascript variables possible? I'm realizing now this may not be a thing.

Thank you very much for your time.

EDIT: Awesome thank you for the input, you nearly instantly solved my problem. I'm now seeing why I got caught up with using $index and could use a bit more help. I currently have this code at displaying my tab names:

```
<nav>
        <ul>   
               <li ng-class="getClass($index)" ng-repeat="tab in tabArray">
                    <a ng-click="toggleSelect($index)" ng-class="getLinkClass($index)">{{tab}}</a>
               </li>
        </ul>
</nav>
```

This isn't using that "tabs" object I introduced you to, but rather "tabArray" which is just an array that has the top-level tab names in order. The toggleSelect uses $index to allow me to change what content is displayed based on what tab is selected and choose which tab gets the active class.

Now back to why I thought I needed $index when I posted this question. The tabs in my "tabs" object are named "tab0", "tab1", etc. Can I use the $index to repeat only the elements from tab0 when the $index is 0? That's why I thought I could utilize a reference like

```
 {{tabs["tab"+$index].title}}
```

or something. Or even name my tabs "0", "1", etc and reference like

```
 {{tabs[$index].title}}
```

in my HTML.

Thank you so much, please let me know if I am being unclear.

Also for reference, my simple toggleSelect method:

```
 $scope.toggleSelect = function(ind){
            $scope.selectedIndex = ind;


            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to modify according to your iterative item, since each of those is relative to the item you're already iterating on.

Altogether, what you have is just 3 for-each loops:

```
<div ng-repeat="tab in tabs">
      <a>{{ tab.title }}</a>
      <ul ng-repeat="section in tab.sections">
         <li>{{ section.title }}</li>
         <ul ng-repeat="child in section.children">
            <li>{{ child.title }}</li>
         </ul>
      </ul>
 </div>
```

**Edit**: To answer your edit, you can change the top line in the above HTML to be:

```
<div ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-if="tabIsActive($index)">
```

And in your controller have:

```
$scope.tabIsActive = function (index) {
     //according to your edit, $scope.selectedIndex should hold the active tab index
     return $scope.selectedIndex == index;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much this immediately worked, but I made an edit asking for help with my next step. Please take a look if you get a chance.

Comment: Thanks again for all the help it made a huge difference. I just posted a new question for this same application that you will probably know how to handle. Please take a look if you have time:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418412/having-trouble-repeating-correct-items-with-nested-ng-repeat-and-ng-if

Comment: @user95227 Answered :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to use the [$index] field, you should just be able to do this:

**tab.title**

and change 'section in tabs'

to '**section in tab.sections**'

and then do

**section.title**

The ng-repeat is already giving you a single element from the tabs array, which this variable is called 'tab'. Same applies for sections.

Comment: Your absolutely right. I made an edit explaining why I think I need to use $index. Please help me out if you can. Thank you so much for the initial quick response.