# Having trouble repeating correct items with nested ng-repeat and ng-if

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following html:

```
            <div ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-if="tabIsActive(tab, $index)">

                  <ul ng-repeat="section in tab.sections">

                     <h2 ng-class="productTitle" ng-repeat="child in section.children" ng-if="sideTabIsActive(section, $index)">
                        <img ng-src="{{ child.productImageURL }}"/>
                        <li>{{ child.title }}</li>
                  </ul>
             </div>
```

This is what the "tabs" javascript object looks like:

[image: Screenshot of tabs object in debugger]

My desired output is the subcategory titles(e.g. children0.title) and image(e.g. children0.productImageURL) listed for each section when that section is selected.

Example desired output:

When Analytical Balances is clicked

```
 (ML image) //which is section0.child0.productImageURL
 ML         //which is section0.child0.title

 (XS image) //which is section0.children1.productImageURL
 XS         //which is section0.child1ren.title
```

Currently, I display this:

When Analytical Balances is clicked:

```
 (ML image) //which is section0.children0.productImageURL
 ML         //which is section0.children0.title

 (XPE image) //which is section1.children0.productImageURL
 XPE         //which is section1.children0.title
```

How can I list both children (and the associated image) for each section based on which section is selected (selectedSideIndex)?

In addition to the above HTML, here is relevant HTML and javascript that I use in my attempt to achieve the desired output:

```
    $scope.toggleSideSelect = function(ind){
            $scope.selectedSideIndex = ind;

    }


$scope.sideTabIsActive = function (tab, $index) {
            var selectedIndexTest = $scope.selectedSideIndex
            return $index==$scope.selectedSideIndex;
```

}

```
            <div ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-if="tabIsActive(tab, $index)">

                  <ul ng-repeat="section in tab.sections" ng-click="toggleSideSelect($index)">
                     <li>{{ section.title }}</li>
                     <ul  ng-repeat="child in section.children">
                        <li>{{ child.title }}</li>
                     </ul>
                  </ul>
             </div>
```

Comment: How is the structure of the global object in JSON?

Comment: @RichardCotrina It's dynamically created from files in the app.data folder so I don't have a javascript code snippet that creates the object to show you. I could write one out, it just would take a bit since it's big. Here is a better shot of the relevant objects from in chrome inspector: http://i.imgur.com/rcdoY4X.png

Does that help?

Comment: Oh, then I recommend you to change the structure of your dinamically generated data to fit a balance between what you need to use and what you need to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there :)

What you need to do is this:

```
<div ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-if="tabIsActive(tab, $index)">

        <ul ng-repeat="section in tab.sections" ng-init="sectionIndex = $index">

            <h2 ng-class="productTitle" ng-repeat="child in section.children" ng-if="sideTabIsActive(section, sectionIndex)">
              <img ng-src="{{ child.productImageURL }}"/>
              <li>{{ child.title }}</li>
       </ul>
</div>
```

This way, using the `ng-init="sectionIndex = $index"` you are saving the `$index` of the section and can use it on the nested `ng-repeat`. It's also possible to use `$parent.$index` but I wouldn't recommend it since the structure might change and you will be left with a bug.

This way, you can call `ng-if="sideTabIsActive(section, sectionIndex)"` using the index of the section, and only your active section's children will get to show.

**Edit:** you should probably change the signature of

`$scope.sideTabIsActive = function (tab, $index)`

to

`$scope.sideTabIsActive = function ($index)`

Since you're not actually using the `tab` in the function. (And if you do, don't forget to change the call to that function from the view as well)

Comment: Thank you sir! You've helped me so much thus far, but now I'm trying to repeat data from an array within the object in a similar fashion and I am struggling again. I don't take your time lately and truly appreciate your help. As you know the project by now, I figured I'd link you to my new question: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28442303/how-to-repeat-elements-pulled-from-an-array-inside-a-javascript-object-literal-w


Let me know if you have any insight or if I am being unclear. I promise I'm trying to figure things out myself first. This is my first time using Angular

Comment: Hi Omri, sorry to bug you after some time now. But this application is working using this dynamically created object and `ng-repeat`. However, I am having trouble setting the initial data to display and just posted a question about it here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28768240/can-i-set-this-something-of-a-service-within-a-nested-object-that-is-dynamical

Sorry if reaching out in this way is inappropriate. You have provided me with more help than anyone before on stack and I thought I would see if you had some time.